# Set Class Variable based on another Class Variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a Class User, where the object will have the variable "Permissions" based on the account type. I'm using a JSON file to define the mapping between account type and permissions.

But every time I run a new instance of this class, I get a blank value for permissions.

```ruby
require 'json'

class User
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :account_type, :permissions

  def initialize(*args)
    @name = args[0]
    @email = args[1]
    @account_type = args[2]
    @permissions = User.get_permissions
  end

  def self.get_permissions
    permissions_file = File.read("permissionsMap.json")
    permissions_map = JSON.parse(permissions_file)
    permissions_map[@account_type]
  end

  def print_details
    puts @name
    puts @email
    puts @account_type
    puts @permissions
  end
end
```

This is the JSON file:

```json
{
  "employee": {
    "accounts": "read",
    "approve headcount": "no",
    "manage finance": "yes"
  },
  "accountant": {
    "accounts": "write",
    "approve headcount": "no",
    "manage finance": "yes"
  },
  "manager": {
    "accounts": "read",
    "approve headcount": "yes",
    "manage finance": "no"
  }
}
```

And this is where I'm initializing an instance of the class User

```ruby
require 'pp'
require 'json'
require_relative 'User'

puts "The runner starts now"

user_x = User.new("ABC","abc@def.com","manager")
user_x.print_details
```

Comment: `@account_type` is `nil` in that context. Consider changing the method signature to `def self.get_permissions(account_type)` and then `@permissions = User.get_permissions(@account_type)`. You see the `get_permissions` method is a class instance method but the initialize method is executed in the context of an instance so the scope is not the same.

Comment: To make this more Ruby-like, consider writing an `inspect` method that replaces what your `print_details` thing does. Also avoid using `*args` when you know exactly what arguments you want. That should be `initialize(name = nil, email = nil, account_type = nil)` if you want them optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the account_type data into the get_permissions method in order for it to work:

```
def initialize(*args)
  @name = args[0]
  @email = args[1]
  @account_type = args[2]
  @permissions = User.get_permissions(@account_type)
end
```

From there you just need to alter the method slightly:

```
def self.get_permissions(acct_type)
  permissions_file = File.read("permissionsMap.json")
  permissions_map = JSON.parse(permissions_file)
  permissions_map(acct_type)
end
```

As mentioned above the scope is not the same the way you have it written.  Also, the other comment is correct that initialize should be structured as:

```
def initialize(name, email, account_type)
  @name = name,
  @email = email,
  @account_type = account_type
  @permissions = User.get_permissions(account_type)
end
```

You can always use =nil if the fields are optional:

```
def initialize(name=nil, email=nil, account_type=nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer occured to me that might also work for you.

```
def initialize(name=nil, email=nil, account_type=nil)
  @name = name
  @email = email
  @account_type = account_type
  @permissions = get_permissions
end

def get_permissions
  permissions_file = File.read("permissionsMap.json")
  permissions_map = JSON.parse(permissions_file)
  permissions_map[@account_type]
end
```

This too would give you the @permissions when you call the print_details method on the User instance.

Hope this answer helped as well.